# Get groovy script free variables in runtime

Tags: java, groovy

I want to know how get all free variables from Groovy script from Java code.

Groovy script:

```
Integer v = a - b;
Integer k = 6 * v;

return k > 0;
```

Call from java:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell(binding);

Script script = groovyShell.parse(...);
script.getFreeVariables(); // == set with "a","b". Want something like this.
```

I know rude way - `script.run()` and then catch exception. In exception I get name of var that I don't pass to the script.

Comment: Why? It's not like your program can supply values for unknown variables. Running scripts generally means that all external variables are well-defined, because those are the values the program *can* supply.

Comment: @Andreas I try embed groovy script in java application. I have some set of potential variables. For example "a", "b", "c". And for some optimization I want to know what variables in script.

Answer (score 2):

groovy:

```
def s0=a+b+2
s1=a+b+1
a=b*2
a+b+3 //the last expression will be returned. the same as return a+b+3
```

java:

```
GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell();
Script script = groovyShell.parse(...);
Map bindings = script.getBinding().getVariables();

bindings.put("a",new Long(1));
bindings.put("b",new Long(2));

Object ret = script.run(); //a+b+3

//and if you changed variables in script you can get their values 
Object aAfter = bindings.get("a"); //4 because `a=b*2` in groovy
Object bAfter = bindings.get("b"); //2 not changed
//also bindings will have all undeclared variables
Object s1 = bindings.get("s1"); //a+b+1

//however declared variables will not be visible - they are local
Object s0 = bindings.get("s0"); //null
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it don't answer me on my question. How can I get "a" and "b" variables from the script?? I need set of two strings (or something like this), where first is "a" and second is "b".

Comment: Okay, I will try to explain. How do you know what exactly put in `bindings`? You saw script and you know that need to pass 2 variables - "a", "b". It's exactly what I want. How do I know what pass to the script if I don't see it?

Comment: @learp Why don't you just pass everything you know? If you pass value for `d`, and script doesn't use it, so what? And if script wants `q`, but you don't know what that is, then what? You fail? That would happen anyway when script runs.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I fail. In my application users may write scripts and they know what vars they may use. The set of vars always the same. But I want to know what vars from the set they use for some optimization.

Comment: @learp *"for some optimization"* Why? Have you profiled the code and seen that you have a problem? Beware [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Answer (score 1):

by default groovy has dynamic resolver at runtime and not at compiletime.

you can try catch access to those properties:

1/

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration;

abstract class MyScript extends groovy.lang.Script{
    public Object getProperty(String name){
        System.out.println("getProperty "+name);
        return new Long(5);
    }
}

CompilerConfiguration cc = new CompilerConfiguration()
cc.setScriptBaseClass( MyScript.class.getName() )

GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell(this.getClass().getClassLoader(),cc);

Script script = groovyShell.parse("1+2+a");

Object ret = script.run();
```

2/

```
GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell();
Script script = groovyShell.parse("1+2+a");
Map bindings = new HashMap(){
    public Object get(Object key){
        System.out.println ("get "+key);
        return new Long(5);
    }
}

script.setBinding(new Binding(bindings));

Object ret = script.run();
```

Comment: thanks for second attempt :) In first sentence you say **by default**. Can I change this behaviour? And I don't see how I can get vars in script.

Comment: there is annotation CompileStatic: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/transform/CompileStatic.html / you can apply it for function or for class but in this case you will not be able to compile script because variables undeclared. probably this could help... ` @groovy.transform.CompileStatic def f() { a+b+55 } `